# Parsing AIDE file to count lines between patterns

Tags: file, perl, grep

ALL,

Perl has a very powerful feature called `grep{} @some_var`.

What I'm trying to do is to modify a script to use grep to parse the AIDE log file and count the number of changed lines.

However for some reason the count is 0.

Could someone please help? Its been a while since I used Perl in production...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
my @lines;
open( INFILE, "aide.log" ) || die "Cannot open input file for processing";
push( @lines, $_ ) while <INFILE>;
close INFILE;
my $matched;
my $count = grep { $matched == 1; $matched = 1 if $_ =~ /[-A-Za-z0-9]*(Added|Changed|Removed)/; $matched = 0 if $_ =~ /[-A-Za-z0-9]*Detail/ } @lines;
print "Number of changed files is ", $count, "!\n";
```

All I need is to count the number of lines between

```
XXX Added
XXX Changed
XXX Deleted
```

and

```
XXX Detail
```

The count shoudn't include those lines.

where `XXX` is just some arbitrary text.

TIA!

[EDIT]

aide.log

```
AIDE version xxx
Executed on 23 September 2019 05:15:00

2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost Added files
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost /tmp/testfile
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost /scripts/aide-parser.pl
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost Changed files
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost /var/log/syslog
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost Deleted files
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost /scripts/aide-parser.pl.old
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost /etc/aide.conf.old
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost /etc/iptables.conf.old
2019-09-23T05:15:00+00 localhost Details of changes
```

Sample output:

```
Number of changed files is 6
```

Only lines with the file name should be counted

[/EDIT]

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus, added. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is indeed by keeping the state, what you are attempting.

A nice tool for that is the [range operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = shift or die "Usage: $0 file\n";

my $beg = qr/Added|Changed|Deleted/; 
my $end = qr/Detail/;

my $cnt;

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) { 
    if (/$beg/ .. /$end/) { 
        ++$cnt unless /$end|$beg/;
    }
}

say $cnt;
```

This prints `6` for the supplied input file.  (Checked by also saving lines on an array and inspecting.)

Comments on posted code

- The `grep` is a filter, and this isn't a good use for it
- The `-w` had been superseded by `use warnings;` in ... year 2000? Kinda 20 years ago. Don't mean to mock, just please update
- Use lexical filehandles (`open my $fh ...`), not globs (`INFILE`). Much better that way
- I'd say that `$matched == 1;` is a typo and that it should be `=` (not `==`)
- No need for `$_ =~ //`, as regex's match operator (as well as the  substitution operator) by default uses `$_`. While reliance on defaults like `$_` can be debated, in this case omitting it clearly improves readability, and this is almost always the case with regex